# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET after ajax request symfony 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

im trying to use ajax to send data from my input to my controller to save data in db but i got this error 
im trying to send data but nothing is received by my controller action

[image: error]
[image: error]

this is my script

```
      <form method="post">
        <textarea id="txt" class="form-control input-lg no-border" rows="2"
                              placeholder="What are you doing?..."></textarea>

    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right mt-5" id="btnpost">POST</button>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></a></li>
        </ul><!-- /.nav nav-pills -->
    </div><!-- /.panel-footer -->
    </form>
    <script>
        $("#btnpost").click(function () {
            var text = $('#txt').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ path("group_new",{'id':id}) }}',
                data: { desc:text }
            })
        })

    </script>
```

this is my controller action

```
   public function newGroupeAction(Request $request , $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //get group description
    $descgrp = $em->getRepository("GroupGroupBundle:Groupe")->findOneBy(array('id'=>$id))->getDescriptiongroupe();

    // get member string
    $str = $em->getRepository("GroupGroupBundle:Groupe")->findOneBy(array('id'=>$id));
    //get array member with arrtibute
    $member = $em->getRepository("GroupGroupBundle:Groupe")->getmemberlist($str->getMembres());

    // get image string
    $stri = $em->getRepository("GroupGroupBundle:Groupe")->findOneBy(array('id'=>$id));
    // get array image with attribute
    $images = $em->getRepository("GroupGroupBundle:Image")->getimagelist($stri->getListimage());


    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $publication = new Publication();
        $des = $request->get('desc');

        $publication->setDescription($des);

        var_dump('test');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($publication);
        $em->flush();
        return new Response('test');
    }

        return $this->render('@GroupGroup/layout/newGroupe.html.twig',array("id"=>$id,"mem"=>$member,"nb"=>sizeof($member),"img"=>$images,"desc"=>$descgrp,"imgnb"=>sizeof($images)));

}
```

Comment: Can you see an error in the log files? Is it just an ajax problem or can you call the url directly and whats the response?

Comment: i didnt understand anything what caused this error i thing when i call the url it shows me my web page but the problem came when i click submit button and calls ajax

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Do you use APCu ?

- Symfony 3
- Windows 10 (64 bits)
- XAMPP 7.0.23 (32 bits)

  - OPcache
  - APCu

And I had problems with AJAX Request : **net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** on Chrome or Apache 2.4 auto-kill process...

**My Solution**(Significantly reduces the error) : Disabling APCU config in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

check your controller see if you can get the value of 'desc' parameter in the request. if you get null for 'desc', it might be the POST data size is over your server limit, therefore, causing your ajax call failed

Answer (score 0):

For me it was php opcache - i commented that in php.ini and then AJAX calls were working.
(It was not in Symfony, but PHP app and Chrome browser.)